# get entered text and exit if the text in mass (tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

good day! here's my code:

```
        import tkinter as tk

        namemass =["dev", "Dev1"]

        self.entry_name = ttk.Entry(self)
        self.entry_name.place(x=200, y=50)

        btn_cancel = ttk.Button(self, text="cancel", command=self.destroy)
        btn_cancel.place(x=300, y=800)

        btn_ok = ttk.Button(self, text="ok") 
        btn_ok.place(x=320, y=170)
```

so, i have 2 buttons and enter box. I want the program to get the text from the enter box and if namemass list have that inside, then exit. in console program i would code it like that:

```
        name = input()
        namemass = ["dev", "Dev1"]
        if name in namemass:
            import sys
            sys.exit()
        else:
            ..........
```

how to do it using tkinter? thank you in advance!

Comment: Please share full code so it's easier for us to reproduce.

Comment: `Entry` widgets have a `textvariable` option which you can set to an instance of a `StringVar`. tkinter [Variable Classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)  object can be "traced" which mean everytime they are read or written, a "callback" function will be called to notify your code that this has happened (and it can react to the variable's current value) — for example it can exit if the value matches some condition.

Answer (score 1):

To fetch the current entry text, use the `get` method:

```
current_text = Entry.get()
```

in your example you can just:

```
from tkinter import *
import sys

def destroy():
    name = entry_name.get()
    if name in namemass:
        sys.exit()

root = Tk()
namemass = ["dev", "Dev1"]

entry_name = Entry(root)
entry_name.pack()

btn_cancel = Button(root, text="cancel", command=destroy)
btn_cancel.pack()

btn_ok = Button(root, text="ok")
btn_ok.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Much easier for Python 3.8, using Walrus. Just add the function for `_ok`. And add command in `btn_ok`.

```
from tkinter import *
import sys


namemass = ["dev", "Dev1"]

def destroy():
    #sys.exit()
    root.destroy()

def _ok():
    if(name_in_list := entry_name.get()) in namemass:
        sys.exit()
             
root = Tk()
 
entry_name = Entry(root)
entry_name.pack()

btn_cancel = Button(root, text="cancel", command=destroy)
btn_cancel.pack()

btn_ok = Button(root, text="ok", command=_ok)
btn_ok.pack()

root.mainloop()
```